# add or modify embeded excel worksheet using python-pptx

Tags: python, excel, python-pptx

I'm trying to embed a single excel table in a pptx using python-pptx.

I have an excel file with a worksheet and I need to copy that only worksheet to my pptx, but I cannot find a way to do it :

I tried :

```py
# Update BP
from pptx.enum.shapes import PROG_ID
# slide = prs.slides[28]

shapes = prs.slides[29].shapes

shape = shapes.add_ole_object(
        'BP_new.xlsx',
        PROG_ID.XLSX,
        left = Inches(1), top = Inches(3)
    )

prs.save('new_ppt.pptx')
```

But it copies the entire file as a link.

The other option would be for me to embed an excel in a template pptx file and then modify the embeded excel in the template, and save the template. But I'm having hard time finding documentation on python-pptx to do so.